# How to parallel for loop inside single region in openMP?

Tags: c++, openmp

I have a recursive program which I want to speed up using openMP. The structure is like below.

I am not familiar with `omp task` and just learnt something from [here](http://openmp.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1231). It seems that I have to wrap `buildTree` in a `omp single` region.

However, I also want to parallelize the for loop inside `buildTree`, how can I achieve that?

```
int main()
{
    #pragma omp parallel 
    {
        #pragma omp single nowait
        buildTree();
    }
}
void buildTree
{
    if(endRecursion)
        return;
    for(int i = 0; i < problemSize; i++)
    {
        // I want to parallelize these code using omp for
    }

    if(problemSizeIsSmall)
    {
        buildTree(subProblemSize); // left subtree
        buildTree(subProblemSize); // right subtree
    }
    else
    {
        #pragma omp task
        {
            buildTree(subProblemSize); // left subtree
        }
        #pragma omp task
        {
            buildTree(subProblemSize); // right subtree
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [nested parallelism](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19205-01/819-5270/aewbc/index.html) in your problem. 
Your code would look like this way in your `main()`:

```
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(2)
buildTree();
```

and in `buildTree()` :

```
omp_set_num_threads(4); // 4 or whatever number of threads you want
#pragma omp parallel for 
for(int i = 0; i < problemSize; i++)
```

Check the section 4.3 `Example 4–2 Calls to OpenMP Routines Within Parallel Regions` of my [first link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19205-01/819-5270/aewbc/index.html) for more details