# OpenMP - Serialise for-loop in Parallel Region which Contains Parallel for-loop

Tags: c, multithreading, openmp

I'm asking a very similar question to [this chap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30294883/how-to-parallel-for-loop-inside-single-region-in-openmp) but there is only one answer there and it hasn't proved useful for me.

I have a parallel region in `main()` with a for-loop which calls the function `new_value()`:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    omp_set_num_threads(4);

#pragma omp parallel default(shared) private(...)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_VALUE; i++)
        new_value(...);
}

    return 0;
}
```

And `new_value()` looks like:

```
void new_value(...)
{
#pragma omp for schedule(static, chunk_width)
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        arr[i] = update();
}
```

The issue I am having is that I do not want the for-loop in `main()` to be parallelised (i.e. ran `MAX_VALUE * 4` times in total).

I essentially want that one loop to be ran serially but the for-loop in `new_value()` to be ran with four threads.

I tried `#pragma omp single` before the loop but it caused the program to deadlock or hang on something. I also tried the nested parallelism approach as suggest by the already [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30294883/how-to-parallel-for-loop-inside-single-region-in-openmp) thread but I got the same result.

Any solutions would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think I understand what you're trying to do, because this has an answer which is too obvious to be correct: if you only want the inner loop to be parallelized, remove the `#pragma omp parallel` on the outer loop and put it on the inner loop instead.

Comment: Theres a lot more inside the parallel region including the setting up of thread specific variables, its just the one loop I want to run in serial (which uses these variables).

Comment: Just wrap it in a critical section then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you kind of overcomplicated it a little. Try this:

```
void new_value(...){
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(4)
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        arr[i] = update();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_VALUE; i++)
        new_value(...);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Theres a lot more inside the parallel region including the setting up of thread specific variables, its just the one loop I want to run in serial (which uses these variables).

Comment: Nope, you're right. It makes a lot more sense just to close it and re-open it.